# Find smallest subset prefixes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Here is my code for this problem. Any bugs, performance in terms of algorithm time complexity, code style advice are appreciated.

The areas which I want to improve, but do not know how to improve are:

1. I sort the strings by length and I'm not sure if it's a smarter idea not using sorting at all.
2. I used a few set operations, which looks a bit ugly. I want to learn smarter ideas.

**Problem:**

> Given a set of strings, return the smallest subset that contains the longest possible
>   prefixes for every string.
>
> If the list is ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf'] return ['foo', 'asdf']

The return is `foo` since `foo` is prefix for `foo` (itself), prefix for `foog` and prefix for `food` (in other words, `foo` could "represent" longer string like `foog` and `food`). Output also contains `asdf` because it is not prefix for any other words in the input list, so output itself.

The empty set is not a correct answer because it does not contain the longest possible prefixes.

**Source code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TrieTreeNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieTreeNode)
        self.isEnd = False
        self.count = 0
    def insert(self, word, result_set):
        node = self
        for i,w in enumerate(word):
            node = node.children[w]
            if node.isEnd:
                result_set[word[:i+1]].add(word)
        node.isEnd = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
    words_length = []
    sorted_words = []
    for w in words:
        words_length.append(len(w))
    for t in sorted(zip(words_length, words)):
        sorted_words.append(t[1])
    result_set = defaultdict(set)
    root = TrieTreeNode()
    for w in sorted_words:
        root.insert(w, result_set)
    match_set = set()
    for k,v in result_set.items():
        for i in v:
            match_set.add(i)
    unmatch_set = set(words) - match_set
    print unmatch_set | set(result_set.keys())
```

Comment: I am afraid the problem is not well defined. An empty set is obviously a solution.

Comment: Why do you have 'asdf' in result if it's not a prefix for first 3 strings?

Comment: The problem you've solved needs a better description.

Comment: @vnp, updated problem statement by clear description how output is coming from by an example, if anything still unclear, please let me know. Any comments on my original question is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Alex, updated problem statement by clear description how output is coming from by an example, if anything still unclear, please let me know. Any comments on my original question is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Mast, updated problem statement by clear description how output is coming from by an example, if anything still unclear, please let me know. Any comments on my original question is highly appreciated.

Comment: @LinMa isn't the shortest prefix between "Foo" and "Bar" nothing? As it'd be `("" + "Foo", "" + "Bar")`. If however it were "Foo" and "Food" then it would be `("Foo" + "", "Foo" + "d")`. Is your code broken, or did it pass the online test?

Comment: I've edited the question to be more specific about what I believe is the purpose of the program.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I should mention empty should not be considered. If you have any ideas on my original question, it will be great. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have for this. If my understanding is good, this is a fairly simple to solve and you do not need anything else than a set.

There might be a better way than rebuilding entirely the set.

```
words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
prefixes = set()

for w in words:
    if any(p for p in prefixes if w.startswith(p)):
        # A prefix exists in the prefixes set.
        continue

    # Re-build the set with all elements not matching the set.
    prefixes = set(p for p in prefixes if not p.startswith(w))
    prefixes.add(w)

print(prefixes)
```

Comment: Thanks FunkySayu, I think you compare each string by one by one and time complexity is `O(n^2)`, do you think using Trie tree or any other solutions help on improving time complexity?

Comment: Hi FunkySayu, I have written a more elegant version of code, your advice is highly appreciated => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150911/find-smallest-subset-prefixes-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Follow PEP8, and upgrade to Python 3.

---

If you want to keep the Trie, then you should simplify your code.
You can get the code to work with `insert`, without the `if` or `result_set`.
You also don't need the `self.count`, and so I'd change your code to:

```
class TrieTreeNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieTreeNode)
        self.is_end = False

    def insert(self, word):
        node = self
        for char in word:
            node = node.children[char]
        node.isEnd = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
    root = TrieTreeNode()
    for word in words:
        root.insert(word)
```

After this you just need a loop that will tell you the roots. The children from root all have one child, otherwise that's the end of the word, or if it reaches the end of a word. And so you should be able to get:

```
output = []
for char, child in root.children.items():
    word = [char]
    while not child.is_end and len(child.children) == 1:
        children = child.children
        letter = children.keys()[0]
        word.append(letter)
        child = children[letter]
    output.append(''.join(word))
print output
```

Comment: Thanks Peilonrayz, love your implementation and vote up, but do not know why you need this condition `len(child.children) == 1`?

Comment: Hi Peilonrayz, I tested and it seems `len(child.children) == 1` is not needed, for example, if input is `abc` and `abd`, we need both as output, `ab` is common prefix, but not a complete word. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Peilonrayz, I have written a more elegant version of code, your advice is highly appreciated => http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150911/find-smallest-subset-prefixes-part-2

Comment: @LinMa Removing just the `and len(child.children) == 1` causes it to output `abc`. Please recheck your code. As for your last comment, please don't do that, I'm under no obligation to help you. But learn SRP.