# Find smallest subset prefixes (part 2)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

Here is my code for this problem. Any bugs, performance in terms of algorithm time complexity, code style advice are appreciated.

This is a continued discussion from ([Find smallest subset prefixes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150467/find-smallest-subset-prefixes)) and since it is new code, I post a new thread.

**Problem:**

> Given a set of strings, return the smallest subset that contains the longest possible
>   prefixes for every string.
>
> If the list is ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf'] return ['foo', 'asdf']

The return is `foo` since `foo` is prefix for `foo` (itself), prefix for `foog` and prefix for `food` (in other words, `foo` could "represent" longer string like `foog` and `food`). Output also contains `asdf` because it is not prefix for any other words in the input list, so output itself.

The empty set is not a correct answer because it does not contain the longest possible prefixes.

**Source code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.isEnd = False
    def insert(self, word):
        node = self
        for w in word:
            node = node.children[w]
        node.isEnd = True
    def find_prefix(self, prefix, result):
        if self.isEnd:
            result.append(''.join(prefix[:]))
            return
        for w, child_node in self.children.items():
            prefix.append(w)
            child_node.find_prefix(prefix, result)
            prefix.pop(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
    root = TrieNode()
    for w in words:
        root.insert(w)
    result = []
    root.find_prefix([], result)
    print result
```

Comment: You can use [os.path.commonprefix()]{https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to find the common prefix of a list of words.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, thanks for the advice. My purpose of this thread is more to learn how to implement the method by myself. Your advice of my original question, -- any bugs, performance in terms of algorithm time complexity, code style advice are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PEP 8

You still haven't followed [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Please:

- Install (for example) [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/).
- You can run it as `pylint filename.py`.
- If you use Vim you can install [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) and every time you save it will run either `flake8` or `pylint`.
- There are alternatives for other text editors please install one, it will save you time in the long run.

## `def main`

You have used `if __name__ == "__main__":` which is good. It is even considered more idiomatic (see [this answer under "An Even Better Way"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/667648)) to do this:

```
def main():
    words = ('foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf')
    root = TrieNode()
    for w in words:
        root.insert(w)
    result = []
    root.find_prefix([], result)
    print result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Immutability

You don't mutate `words`. I would turn it into a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dair, from performance (in terms of algorithm time complexity) perspective, do you have any better ideas than using Trie Tree?

Comment: @LinMa: I'm not really an expert in this, but the Wikipedia article dedicated to Tries provides some discussion about use cases and alternatives.

Comment: It is ok Dair, I will keep the thread open for a few days to see if anyone else have good ideas.